# Gensim LDA - Default number of iterations

Tags: python, topic-modeling, gensim

I wish to know the default number of iterations in **gensim**'s LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) algorithm. I don't think the documentation talks about this. (Number of iterations is denoted by the parameter **iterations** while initializing the **LdaModel** ). Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checked the module's files in the *python/Lib/site-packages* directory. The constructor is something like this -

```
def __init__(self, corpus=None, num_topics=100, id2word=None,
                 distributed=False, chunksize=2000, passes=1, update_every=1,
                 alpha='symmetric', eta=None, decay=0.5, offset=1.0,
                 eval_every=10, iterations=50, gamma_threshold=0.001)
```

So, the default number of iterations stands at 50.

Comment: Difference between passes and iterations?

Comment: A little bit of googling - 

The passes parameter is indeed unique to gensim. It essentially allows LDA
to see your corpus multiple times and is very handy for smaller corpora.

The iterations parameter puts a limit on how many times LDA will execute
the E-Step for each document (see repeat-until loop in algorithm 2 in
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/HoffmanBleiBach2010b.pdf),
meaning that some documents may not converge in time. You can set this as high as you would like (or have time for).


Link : http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.gensim/4732

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', 
    level=logging.INFO)
```

It will tell you

```
running batch LDA training, 17 topics, 10 passes over the supplied corpus of 1130 documents, updating model once every 1130 documents, evaluating perplexity every 1130 documents, iterating 50x with a convergence threshold of 0.001000
```

Answer (score 0):

The default number of iterations = 50